# CPU and RAM monitorization by parent id

Tags: cpu, ps, ram

I'm trying to monitor the CPU and RAM usage (in % of total for example) of a given process wich may spawn several processes. The parent process is `/bin/rscw` so I get its pid by

`ppid_bl=$(ps -ef | grep [b]in/rscw | awk '{print $2}')`

and then I try something like

`ps -ppid $ppid_bl S` **(1)**

because in `man ps` it appears

`-ppid   Select by parent process ID. This selects the processes
            with a parent process ID in pidlist. That is, it
            selects processes that are children of those listed in
            pidlist.`

`Output format S        Sum up some information, such as CPU usage, from dead
                       child processes into their parent. This is useful for
                       examining a system where a parent process repeatedly
                       forks off short-lived children to do work.`

My question is, is my approach right? I'm getting `ps` error with **(1)**, and this it's because I'm not using the right `ps` syntax, but maybe I'm not doing things right even with a correct syntax.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to use two dashes for this parameter, like

```
$ ps --ppid 1
```

My version:

```
$ ps --version
procps-ng version 3.3.4
```

Comment: Indded, `ps -o pcpu,pmem,pid,user,cmd --ppid 1` did the thing. Thank you.